# Making letters uppercase using re.sub in python?

Tags: python, regex

In many programming languages, the following

find `foo([a-z]+)bar` and replace with `GOO\U\1GAR`

will result in the entire match being made uppercase. I can't seem to find the equivalent in python; does it exist?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) that will allow you to do this, here is an example:

```
 def upper_repl(match):
     return 'GOO' + match.group(1).upper() + 'GAR'
```

And an example of using it:

```
 >>> re.sub(r'foo([a-z]+)bar', upper_repl, 'foobazbar')
 'GOOBAZGAR'
```

Comment: I suppose that will have to do although it is awfully complicated, considering.

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately this **\U\1** syntax could never work in Python because \U in a string literal indicates the beginning of a 32-bit hex [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). For example, `"\U0001f4a9" == ""`.

However there are easy alternative to Perl's case conversion escapes available by using a replacement *function*. In `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` the replacement `repl` is usually a string, but it can also be a callable. If it is a callable, [it's passed the Match object and must return a replacement string to be used](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0c84593275969d9b8f42e75abb2638b69d5b5f4a/Lib/re/__init__.py#L183-L185).

So, for the example given in the question, this is possible:

```
>>> string = "fooquuxbar"
>>> pattern = "foo([a-z]+)bar"
>>> re.sub(pattern, lambda m: f"GOO{m.group(1).upper()}GAR", string)
'GOOQUUXGAR'
```

Here is a table of other string methods which might be useful for similar case conversions.

| Modifier | Description | Example | Python callable to use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \U | Uppercase | foo BAR --> FOO BAR | [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) |
| \L | Lowercase | foo BAR --> foo bar | [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) or [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) |
| \I | Initial capital | foo BAR --> Foo Bar | [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) |
| \F | First capital | foo BAR --> Foo bar | [`str.capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) |

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a replacement string (template), you may not be keen on swapping it out with the verbosity of `m.group(1)+...+m.group(2)+...+m.group(3)`... Sometimes it's nice to have a tidy little string.

You can use the `MatchObject`'s [expand()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function to evaluate a template for the match in the same manner as [sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), allowing you to retain as much of your original template as possible. You can use `upper` on the relevant pieces.

```
re.sub(r'foo([a-z]+)bar', lambda m: 'GOO' + m.expand(r'\1GAR').upper(), 'foobazbar')
```

While this would not be particularly useful in the example above, and while it does not aid with complex circumstances, it may be more convenient for longer expressions with a greater number of captured groups, such as a MAC address censoring regex, where you just want to ensure the full replacement is capitalized or not.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you might need to explicitly define the expansion string as regex, depending on the interpreter: `m.expand(r'\1')` works, while `m.expand('\1')` is treated as ASCII 001 (at least on 3.7.2).

Answer (score 3):

You could use some variation of this:

```
s = 'foohellobar'
def replfunc(m):
     return m.groups()[0]+m.groups()[1].upper()+m.groups()[2]
re.sub('(foo)([a-z]+)(bar)',replfunc,s)
```

gives the output:

```
'fooHELLObar'
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming across this on google...

You can also use re.sub to match repeating patterns. For example, you can convert a string with spaces to camelCase:

```
def to_camelcase(string):
  string = string[0].lower() + string[1:]  # lowercase first
  return re.sub(
    r'[\s]+(?P<first>[a-z])',              # match spaces followed by \w
    lambda m: m.group('first').upper(),    # get following \w and upper()
    string) 

to_camelcase('String to convert')          # --> stringToConvert
```