# Python how to scan string and and use upper() between two characters?

Tags: python, string

I'm a beginner so please forgive me for that question. I would like write program which magnifies letters between characters "`<" and ">"`

For example
*Input*:

```
<html> randomchars </html>
```

*Output*:

```
<HTML> randomchars </HTML>
```

How to do that ?

I only wrote this but this magnifies all words.

```
while True:             
    inp = input()
    if inp == "":
        break
    elif inp =="<":
        inp=inp.upper()
        print(inp)
    else:
        print(inp)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you really tried *this* code?  For me, it does nothing to the text.  Remember, inp is the *entire* string.  If you enter anything but a single less-than sign, it simply prints the output.

Comment: What about `<span> <hey <annoy!>> </span>` ? Regular expressions are not a good choice to parse HTML. Other than knowing when to escape characters, there is the matter of nested tags which will lead to nested headaches. Please use a suitable tool like beautifulsoup for this: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  If it's as simple as you state (perhaps part of a homework assignment), my answer might work for you.  If you're trying to attack full HTML syntax, then the solution is likely available as an open-source package -- and beyond your present personal programming resources.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: There’s no regular expression in this code, and parsing HTML into a DOM is overkill for capitalizing tags. You just need a little bit of state. `<hey <annoy!>>` isn’t even valid HTML.

Comment: @minitech that's the point - it's just text inside a span.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: If it were text inside a span, it would be encoded correctly as `&lt;hey &lt;annoy!&gt;&gt;`; maybe parsing invalid HTML isn’t a requirement. Better examples might be `<span data-attr="<hey!>"></span>` or `<script>1 < 2 > 1;</script>`, which are valid.

Comment: You're right. But I can't look at this. This is why I avoid these questions usually. This is not the right tool unless you're just checking something for a couple of minutes. This will only get exponentially worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's "repair" the while loop to get the continuation control out of the way.  Instead of

```
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == "":
        break
    <process the input>
```

use

```
inp = input()
while inp != "":
    <process the input>
    inp = input()
```

---

Now, for the loop innards.  We need to process "inp" to throw the marked characters into upper case.  We also want to do this in a fashion a beginner can understand, matching the original loop flow.

You need to iterate through the characters in the input string.  Set a boolean flag to tell you whether or not you're in a marked area.

```
    upper_area = False
    out_str = ""
    for char in inp:
        if char == '>':
            upper_area = False
        elif char == '<':
            upper_area = True
        elif upper_area:
            char = char.upper()
        out_str += char
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Brillant!

Comment: Actually, it's 'brilliant' only that it solves your problem at your current skill level.  As you'll soon learn, there are *much* better ways to do this in Python.  Among other things, it's much better to find the next '<' and simply concatenate all the stuff in front of that as a string, instead of one character at a time.  I tried to stick with the feeling of *your* code.

Comment: Your first suggestion about moving the condition and doubling the input isn’t an improvement.

Comment: That's opinion; on my team, it's an improvement in that it restores the loop's structural integrity.

Comment: So is your team’s opinion so vital that it needs to be the first change in an unrelated problem?

Comment: Nope; it's the top-down approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub);

```
print re.sub(r"(</?\w+>)", lambda up: up.group(1).upper(), "<tag>input</tag>")
```

`/?\w+` breakdown below, assuming you can see parenthesis `()` makes the group and we are trying to match between brackets `<>`;

- `?` will greedily match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE.
  Therefore, `/?` will match both start and finish tags.
- `\w` will match any Unicode word character, including a-z, A-Z, and 0-9.
- `+` will greedily match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE.

This will match most tags and then you can replace the tag after converting to uppercase inline using the lambda function, `up`.

Comment: `<([A-Z])\1>`? What? This will replace `<XX>` with `XX`, where `X` is any *already uppercase* letter.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regular expression to match the tags, and pass a function to modify the match. See this previous answer:
[Making letters uppercase using re.sub in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934477/making-letters-uppercase-using-re-sub-in-python)

```
def upper_repl(match):
    return match.group(1).upper()

re.sub('(<[^>]*>)', upper_repl, '<span> <hey <annoy!>> </span>')
'<SPAN> <HEY <ANNOY!>> </SPAN>'
```

Comment: He most definitely does **not** want to use regular expressions to parse html.

Comment: He didn't say anything about parsing HTML. He just wants to convert the characters to uppercase.